# All along, all I was running away from was "me" or "myself"?

Tags: word-choice, syntactic-analysis, personal-pronouns, reflexives

1. All along, all I was running away from was ***me***.
2. All along, all I was running away from was ***myself***.

Which is (more) correct?

I understand that if the sentence was simply "I was running away from ***me/myself***," ***myself*** would be the right word to use, because the subject and object are the same. 
I'm just unsure with the second "all" in the sentence.

I've seen lyrics like "all I was searching for was ***me***"  or titles like "all I was looking for was ***me***." I know those could be incorrect.

Could someone please confirm which of the two sentences above is more correct?

Answer (score 5):

The second option you provided is the more correct of the two:

> All along, all I was running away from was ***myself***.

The "All along" in your sentence is sort of self-contained and doesn't matter for this question.

---

*Myself* should be usually be used with the subject pronoun *I,* since it's a reflexive pronoun.

*Me* is an object pronoun, the verb acts upon it.

> **Paint me green.**
>
> and
>
> **I painted myself green**

But this is weird and wrong:

> **I painted me green**

Generally speaking, song lyrics are not a good source for grammar. Plenty of artistic/poetic liberty can be taken to make a rhyme or a sentiment work.

Comment: The last example sounds wrong, unless you're a pirate. *I painted me green, arrrgh.*

Answer (score 3):

Correct:

> I was running from myself.

Why? "Myself" is a *reflexive pronoun* [1](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/how-to-use-myself-and-other-reflexive-pronouns), which are nouns that are used in conjunction with the word that they describe. Hence, these words **reflect** the word to which they refer. In this case, "myself" is the reflexive pronoun, and "I" is the noun to which "myself" refers.

Put more simply:

- Use "myself" when the actor is *you*
- Use "me" when the actor is *someone other than you*

The same can be said for other reflexive nouns, such as "herself", "himself", "themselves", etc. For example:

> She was running away from herself

In this case, *she* is acting upon *herself*.